# Find the sum of the following infinite series $e^{-x}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i.x^i}{i!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Find the sum of the following infinite series $$e^{-x}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{i.x^i}{i!}$$

The summation looks like an exponential series but how to tackle that?$$ 0+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{2x^2}{2!}+...$$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for clarity

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{nx^n}{n!} = x\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = xe^x.$$

So $e^{-x}$ times that is just $x$.  Is this what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{ix^i}{i!}
=xD(e^x)=xe^x.
$$
So 
$$
e^{-x}\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{ix^i}{i!}\right)
=e^{-x}xe^x
=x.
$$